# Why can't I connect to MongoDB Atlas with GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, github-actions, mongodb-atlas

I want to create a workflow that automatically scrapes reviews of an app from Google Play Store at a scheduled time every day and stores it in my collection in MongoDB Atlas. So first, I created a Python script called `scraping_daily.py` that will scrape 5,000 new reviews and filter out any that were previously collected. When I tested it and ran it manually, the script worked perfectly fine. Here's what the script looks like:

```py
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews, reviews_all, app
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create a connection to MongoDB
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<MY_USERNAME>:<MY_PASSWORD>@project1.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client["vidio"]
collection = db["google_play_store_reviews"]

# Load the data from MongoDB
df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
df = df.drop("_id", axis=1)
df = df.sort_values("at", ascending=False)

# Collect 5000 new reviews
result = reviews(
    "com.vidio.android",
    lang="id",
    country="id",
    sort=Sort.NEWEST,
    count=5000
)
new_reviews = pd.DataFrame(result[0])
new_reviews = new_reviews.fillna("empty")

# Filter the scraped reviews to exclude any that were previously collected
common = new_reviews.merge(df, on=["reviewId", "userName"])
new_reviews_sliced = new_reviews[(~new_reviews.reviewId.isin(common.reviewId)) & (~new_reviews.userName.isin(common.userName))]

# Update MongoDB with any new reviews that were not previously scraped
if len(new_reviews_sliced) > 0:
    new_reviews_sliced_dict = new_reviews_sliced.to_dict("records")

    batch_size = 1_000
    num_records = len(new_reviews_sliced_dict)
    num_batches = num_records // batch_size

    if num_records % batch_size != 0:
        num_batches += 1

    for i in range(num_batches):
        start_idx = i * batch_size
        end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size, num_records)
        batch = new_reviews_sliced_dict[start_idx:end_idx]

        if batch:
            collection.insert_many(batch)
```

Next, I want to schedule my script using GitHub Actions. Just like what I followed from YouTube tutorials, I created an `actions.yml` file in the `.github/workflows` folder. Here's what the YAML file looks like:

```yaml
name: Scraping Google Play Reviews

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: 50 16 * * * # At 16:50 every day

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check out the repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: set up python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: install requirements
        run:
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: execute the script
        run: python -m scraping_daily.py
```

However, it always throws an error when it executes my script. The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/runner/work/vidio_google_play_store_reviews/vidio_google_play_store_reviews/scraping_daily.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1139, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1740, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1685, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 538, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 554, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.10/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 238, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-01.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-02.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-00.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 300.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 641dd5b78e0efba394e00ffc, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-00.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-00.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-01.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-01.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-02.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-02.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to increase the timeout setting by adding `serverSelectionTimeoutMS=300000` inside `MongoClient()`, but it still gave me the same error. How can I solve this?

By the way, I'm using a Windows machine (I'm not sure if it's useful information though).

Comment: Have you verified the configuration whether `ac-dc8axn9-shard-00-01.lpu4kvx.mongodb.net:27017` is accessible for your GHA workflow run? Did you do anything specific to your machine to make it work locally?

Comment: Could you ping to your mongo db atlas from github action or another host different to your localhost? https://github.com/ruby/net-telnet

Answer (score 1):

To enable access to your MongoDB database via GitHub Actions, you need to add the IP address and select the **Allow Access from Anywhere** option.

Comment: It is a bad solution. You are opening you db not only for your pipeline, but you are creating a very dangerous vulnerability on your DB.

Comment: @bpedroso this creates indeed a dangerous DB vulnerability but I am also struggling to find another solution... I am wondering if you can suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than allowing *any* IP to access the cluster, you can add the runner's IP for the duration of the job:

- As a secret, supply [API credentials](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/configure-api-access/#std-label-create-org-api-key) with the Project Owner role. **Note** that you must also permit access to any IP for the Atlas administration API itself ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/configure-api-access/#optional--require-an-ip-access-list-for-the-atlas-administration-api)).
- Make a request to e.g. https://checkip.amazonaws.com to find out what the specific runner's public IP is:

  ```yaml
  - name: Get the public IP of the runner
    id: get-ip
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "ip-address=$(curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  ```
- Make a request to the MongoDB Atlas API [`POST /groups/{groupId}/accessList`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/v2/#tag/Project-IP-Access-List/operation/createProjectIpAccessList) to permit access to that IP:

  ```yaml
  - name: Permit the runner to access MongoDB Atlas
    id: allow-ip
    shell: bash
    run: |
      curl \
         --data '[{"ipAddress": "${{ steps.get-ip.outputs.ip-address }}", "comment": "GitHub Actions Runner"}]' \
         --digest \
         --header 'Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json' \
         --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         --user "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" \
         "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/$GROUP_ID/accessList"
    env:
      GROUP_ID: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_GROUP_ID }}
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      USERNAME: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_PUBLIC_KEY }}
  ```
- After the access has happened, on success *or* failure, make a request to [`DELETE /groups/{groupId}/accessList/{entryValue}`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/v2/#tag/Project-IP-Access-List/operation/deleteProjectIpAccessList) to revoke access:

  ```yaml
  - name: Revoke the runner's access to MongoDB Atlas
    if: always() && steps.allow-ip.outcome == 'success'
    shell: bash
    run: |
      curl \
         --digest \
         --header 'Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2023-02-01+json' \
         --request 'DELETE' \
         --user "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" \
         "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/$GROUP_ID/accessList/${{ steps.get-ip.outputs.ip-address }}"
    env:
      GROUP_ID: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_GROUP_ID }}
      PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      USERNAME: ${{ secrets.ATLAS_PUBLIC_KEY }}
  ```

Another way to do this, including automatically applying the post-job step, is in a [custom JavaScript action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action) (using [`runs.post`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runspost) to make the `DELETE` request). I have [published](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/allow-mongodb-atlas-ip) such an action to the marketplace.